# Is there a simple chat api available to use with android?

Tags: android, api, chat

I am prototyping an application as a proof of concept which needs a chat feature, but I don't want to implement a full fledged chat. Is there "chat as a service" I can use along with android?

(Yes, I have been spoiled by twilio)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want XMPP or something like it, here is an article that explains how to do it on Android: http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/

You should probably click on the original article in that link so you can get a better backdrop.

Comment: Original Artical Here : http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/